# JQ 1.5: Timestamp / date transformation produce huge file

Tags: json, jq

I using jq 1.5 under a Windows 10 powershell enviroment to transform json files and import them to a MS SQL database. The original json file is around 1,1mb. I stored the file here: [Json origin file](https://jsonblob.com/fa1e2b57-e7e8-11e8-9007-8176f625eaf6). I use following jq command to transform the data:

```
[.legs[] | {Legid: .legId, Farecode: .fareBasisCode, Travelduration: .travelDuration, Traveldistance: .totalTravelDistance, Distanceunit: .totalTravelDistanceUnits, Refundable: .isRefundable , Nonstop: .isNonStop, Departure_Airport: .segments[].departureAirportName, Departure_Code: .segments[].departureAirportCode, Arrival_Airport: .segments[].arrivalAirportName, Arrival_Code: .segments[].arrivalAirportCode, Departure_Time: .segments[].departureTimeEpochSeconds, Arrival_Time: .segments[].arrivalTimeEpochSeconds, Airline: .segments[].airlineName, Airline_Code: .segments[].airlineCode, Flight_Number: .segments[].flightNumber, Equipment: .segments[].equipmentDescription}]
```

That command produce following file [transformed file](https://jsonblob.com/6ea23d97-e7ea-11e8-9007-09a55fb13d8c). Now i had to transform the UNIX Timestamps to Dates. So i modified the command:

```
[.legs[] | {Legid: .legId, Farecode: .fareBasisCode, Travelduration: .travelDuration, Traveldistance: .totalTravelDistance, Distanceunit: .totalTravelDistanceUnits, Refundable: .isRefundable , Nonstop: .isNonStop, Departure_Airport: .segments[].departureAirportName, Departure_Code: .segments[].departureAirportCode, Arrival_Airport: .segments[].arrivalAirportName, Arrival_Code: .segments[].arrivalAirportCode, Departure_Time: .segments[].departureTimeEpochSeconds, Arrival_Time: .segments[].arrivalTimeEpochSeconds, Airline: .segments[].airlineName, Airline_Code: .segments[].airlineCode, Flight_Number: .segments[].flightNumber, Equipment: .segments[].equipmentDescription}] | .[].Departure_Time |= todate | .[].Arrival_Time |= todate
```

The transformed file without date Transformation have around 3 mb. After the date Transformation the file have around 40 mb. I think i have a logical error in my command, but cant find it. Tips?

Regards
Timo

Comment: Instead of pasting your JSON in another site, it would help if you update your question with a minimal JSON example on which you could pinpoint where your jq filter goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of iteration (`.segments[]`) causes multiplicative behavior: in your case, since there are four cases in which `.segments|length` is 2, you get a 2^10 expansion locally, four times.

In situations such as this, it would make sense to use a small but well-chosen subset of the data (or maybe more easily, an artificial dataset) to check the code.

Perhaps what you intended is something more like:

```
[ .legs[] | range(0; .segments|length) as $i | .... ]
```